# Stopping touchpad clicks registering as right-clicks when there's another finger already on the pad

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

Often I will drag the cursor to a particular location with my right finger and then press the *touchpad* with my left finger to *left-click*, whilst my right finger is still on the pad. This works in Windows and other laptops I've used before, but in Ubuntu 18.04 these keep registering as *right-click*-s whenever my fingers are too close together. 

This makes clicking and dragging particularly annoying as I have to lift my other finger off the pad before initiating the click.

Basically I want to configure my touchpad to ignore the presence of a second finger when it is clicked, and just do a *left-click* regardless, but can't spot a relevant setting in `xinput --list-props`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `libinput Click Method Enabled` was the setting I was looking for in `xinput --list-props`

The previous setting,`0 1`, would determine the click type based upon how many fingers were on the pad.

Changing to `1 0` determines click type by the area of the pad that is clicked (left, middle, right), so a click is always a left click as long as it's on the left side of the pad.